# Recursive Search Not Working

Tags: c++, recursion

I have been building binary tree in C++. I tried to add search element functionality via recursive method.

It's not working properly.

Please see below code and guide.

```
bool Binarytree::SearchElement(node* SearchPtr,int key,bool found) {
    if(SearchPtr->data==key)
        found=true;

    if(SearchPtr==NULL  || found==true)
        return found;


    else
    {
        if(SearchPtr->data>key)
        { cout<<endl<<"Seaching in Left Sub tree"<<endl;
            SearchElement(SearchPtr->left,key,found);
        }
        else
        {   cout<<endl<<"Seaching in right Sub tree"<<endl;
            SearchElement(SearchPtr->right,key,found);
        }

    }

}
```

The function `SearchElement` is called as below: (Note value 1 is not present in tree)

```
if(SearchElement(root,1,false))
        cout<<endl<<"Element Found"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<endl<<"Element not Found"<<endl;
```

Comment: Could be a different issue (like an invalid tree), but note that you're not returning anything when `SearchPtr==NULL  || found==true` is `false`.

Comment: when found == false , we do left or right recursive calling till pointer becomes null. and when it becomes null we return a value.

Comment: @B.K. I'm rolling back your edit because it's not "formatting", it changes the substance of the code. If there are syntax errors in a question, don't correct them by editing; point them out in an answer or a comment. The errors you're correcting may be part of the reason the OP is having a problem. A *formatting* edit is one that changes the presentation for organization/readability *without* changing what the code does.

Comment: @AdiInbar Fair enough.

Comment: @user3440629 you do return a value from the last invocation, but not the upstream ones. Doesn't your compiler warn you you're not returning a value on every path? If you're convinced that's not the problem, please post a SSCCE.

Comment: Please define "It's not working properly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything. Once you've found `NULL` you need to return `false`. And if you've found the element you need to return `true`. Once you've known whether the element is present or not, you need to return for all the recursive calls. Check the code below.

Note: You've mentioned binary tree and searched like a binary search tree. Considering it is a binary search tree, it will be like this:

```
bool Binarytree::SearchElement(node* SearchPtr,int key) {
    if(SearchPtr->data==key)
        return true;

    if(SearchPtr==NULL)
        return false;


    if(SearchPtr->data < key) //not greater than, but less than
    { cout<<endl<<"Seaching in Left Sub tree"<<endl;
        return SearchElement(SearchPtr->left,key);
    }
    else
    {   cout<<endl<<"Seaching in right Sub tree"<<endl;
        return SearchElement(SearchPtr->right,key);
    }

}
```

If it is binary tree, you'll have to traverse the whole tree to find whether the element is present or not. Like this:

```
bool Binarytree::SearchElement(node* SearchPtr,int key) {
    if (SearchPtr==NULL)
        return false;

    if(SearchPtr->data==key)
        return true;

    if (SearchElement(SearchPtr->left,key))
        return true;

    if (SearchElement(SearchPtr->right,key))
        return true;

    return false;

}
```

Comment: @user3440629 again, what's your [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) look like? Did you try debugging it?